# Push Notification Badges not Coming

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am using this coding for apple push notification, push notifications are coming but they are coming without any badges, any suggestion what is wrong with this code, that I am not getting badges. I already check the setting tab, and badges are on there.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] 
     registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | 
      UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | 
      UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];

[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;

}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken1 { 

    NSString *str = [NSString 
                     stringWithFormat:@"%@",deviceToken1];
    NSLog(@"%@",str);

    self.deviceToken = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",str];
    NSLog(@"dev --- %@",self.deviceToken);
    self.deviceToken = [self.deviceToken stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:@""];
    self.deviceToken = [self.deviceToken stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    self.deviceToken = [self.deviceToken stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""];
    NSLog(@"dev --- %@",self.deviceToken);


}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)err { 

    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Error: %@", err];
    NSLog(@"%@",str);    

}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    NSLog(@"Received notification: %@", userInfo);
    //[self addMessageFromRemoteNotification:userInfo];

    NSString* alertValue = [[userInfo valueForKey:@"aps"] valueForKey:@"badge"];
    NSLog(@"my message-- %@",alertValue);
    int badgeValue= [alertValue intValue];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:badgeValue];


}
```

Comment: Have you tried checking `badgeValue` is set properly?

Comment: What about your server side code?.

Comment: there was a problem with my server, i just find out that badge value has to be implicitly set as integer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There was a problem with my server side coding as I just find out that badge value has to be implicitly set as integer to get desired result.

As I'm getting null value in badge value.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced this issue before , hope this helps

```
{"aps":{"alert":"dsfdsfsdfsdfsdfdfdfsdfsdf","badge":1,"sound":"a"}}
```

make sure there is no double quotation mark on badge value