# Push Notification Badge Count Not Updating

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4, apple-push-notifications

this is my code for apple push notification, when the application is running and notification coming i am incrementing the badge count and getting desired result when i click home button, on app icon. but when i am not running my application and notification comes, it didn't auto increment badge count and remains to only 1. the value 1 is coming from server. can any one point out where i am doing wrong. thanks in advance.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
    userMessageCounter = @"0";
    postType = 0;
    joinedStreamChecker = 0;
    OwnerValue = 0;
    pushValue = 1;
    badgeValue =0;

    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    // Add the navigation controller's view to the window and display.
    [self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];


    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] 
     registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | 
      UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | 
      UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];


    //[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
    //(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
    // [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeNewsstandContentAvailability | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];

    UIRemoteNotificationType types = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];
    if (types == UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone) 
    {
        pushValue = 0;


        NSLog(@"notification off");
    }

    return YES;
}


- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken1 { 

    NSString *str = [NSString 
                     stringWithFormat:@"%@",deviceToken1];
    NSLog(@"%@",str);

    self.deviceToken = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",str];
    NSLog(@"dev --- %@",self.deviceToken);
    self.deviceToken = [self.deviceToken stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:@""];
    self.deviceToken = [self.deviceToken stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    self.deviceToken = [self.deviceToken stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""];
    NSLog(@"dev --- %@",self.deviceToken);


}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)err { 

    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Error: %@", err];
    NSLog(@"%@",str);    

}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    NSLog(@"Received notification: %@", userInfo);
    //[self addMessageFromRemoteNotification:userInfo];

    NSString* alertValue = [[userInfo valueForKey:@"aps"] valueForKey:@"badge"];
    NSLog(@"my message-- %@",alertValue);
    badgeValue= [alertValue intValue];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber += badgeValue;
    //badgeValue = [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber;
    //[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber=0;
    //[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:badgeValue];


}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Push Notification Badges not Coming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9734451/push-notification-badges-not-coming)

Comment: i did not get the answer that's why i posted the question here.

Comment: That's not how it works. Edit your original question or add a bounty. On the original one you say it is working, anyway?

Comment: ok i will do it from next time thanks.

Comment: Here is the solution for exact same problem
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26117430/pushwhoosh-remote-notification/26119399#26119399

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple does not keep track of your data for you. It only shows what you tell it to. Thus, you have to store the count on your server, then tell apple the new badge number when you send the alert. Typically this is done by having the app phone home when launched telling your servers to zero out the count of unread notifications.

Comment: how can my server know that the person have read or not read that message??

Comment: This is for you to figure out. The easy way is to make both 0 when opening the app.

Comment: iam doing that by putting the code in application did finish launching [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;

Comment: you would also have to tell your server to reset the server value so the next notification starts at 1.